# The effect of dark lines in the Sun's spectrum on reflected paint/ color

Tags: visible-light, sun, spectroscopy

Its well known that the Sun's spectrum is not continuous, and that there are dark bands within the suns spectrum. Is it possible to produce a color of paint that is bright in, say, indoor lighting and dark in the sunlight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In theory, perhaps.  It is possible, using multilayer dielectric coatings, to produce a surface which is reflective in very narrow bands (in this case, the Sun's dark lines)and transmissive (or absorptive) elsewhere.  In practice, the spectral "blurring" caused by atmospheric transmission/absorption/re-emission effects would make this effect pretty much impossible to achieve.

But with "paint," no.